# javascript / jquery: how do I get javascript to trigger a key typed event, with a specific key?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my script to pretend like it is actually typing, so that the rest of my scripts that listen for changes work. Just trying to do some automation here.

Anyway,

How would one get javascript / jquery to prentend to type, say a space?

I tried this:

```
typeBox.val(" ");
typeBox.trigger('keypress');
```

But it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the event into the trigger call

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = e.charCode = e.keyCode = 32;
typeBox.trigger(e);
```

Read the docs here:

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function textsizer(e){
var evtobj=window.event? event : e //distinguish between IE's explicit event object (window.event) and Firefox's implicit.
var unicode=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode
var actualkey=String.fromCharCode(unicode)
if (actualkey=="a")
document.body.style.fontSize="120%"
if (actualkey=="z")
document.body.style.fontSize="100%"
}
document.onkeypress=textsizer
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [jQuery.trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and [jQuery.Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
e.which =//someKeyValue **
typeBox.trigger('keypress', e);
```

**[someValue](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx)